# How to pass JavaScript array to a function in DataTable()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I want to [replicate the following code in DataTables example](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html).
What it does is simply displaying a drop down list for every column.
These drop down lists can be seen at the bottom of the table.

But for my case, instead of using HTML table, I'd like to pass JS array.
Here is the code

```js
var dataSet = [
  ["Airi Satou", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "5407", "2008/11/28", "$162,700"],
  ["Angelica Ramos", "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)", "London", "5797", "2009/10/09", "$1,200,000"],
  ["Gavin Joyce", "Developer", "Edinburgh", "8822", "2010/12/22", "$92,575"],
  ["Jennifer Chang", "Regional Director", "Singapore", "9239", "2010/11/14", "$357,650"],
  ["Brenden Wagner", "Software Engineer", "San Francisco", "1314", "2011/06/07", "$206,850"],
  ["Fiona Green", "Chief Operating Officer (COO)", "San Francisco", "2947", "2010/03/11", "$850,000"],
  ["Shou Itou", "Regional Marketing", "Tokyo", "8899", "2011/08/14", "$163,000"],
  ["Martena Mccray", "Post-Sales support", "Edinburgh", "8240", "2011/03/09", "$324,050"],
  ["Unity Butler", "Marketing Designer", "San Francisco", "5384", "2009/12/09", "$85,675"]
];


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        data: dataSet,
        columns: [{title: "Name"}, 
                  {title: "Position"}, 
                  {title: "Office"}, 
                  {title: "Extn."}, 
                  {title: "Start date"}, 
                  {title: "Salary"}],
        
        // This function doesn't work as expected.
        // It should create the drop down list for every column
        // see DT link given earlier.
        initComplete: function (setting, json) {
            this.api().columns().every( function () {
                var column = this;
                var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                    .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                    .on( 'change', function () {
                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                            $(this).val()
                        );
 
                        column
                            .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                            .draw();
                    } );
 
                column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                    select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                } );
            } );
        } 
        
    } );
} );
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/dt/jq-2.1.4,dt-1.10.9,b-1.0.3,b-flash-1.0.3/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/dt/jq-2.1.4,dt-1.10.9,b-1.0.3,b-flash-1.0.3/datatables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display" width="100%">
```

Notice that when you run the code snippet, the function under `initComplete` did not work. The final result I expect it to show a drop down list like this:

[image]

What's the way to go about it?

Comment: this is a Javascript Array, not JSON

Comment: @Hacketo: Ok. I updated accordingly.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "not work"? Does this function not run at all?

Comment: @hindmost: Using my code  above, the final table did not show the drop down list. I updated my OP to clarify.

Comment: Insert some `console.log` output inside `every`'s callback to learn if it invoked.

Comment: Seems the datatable's forum has a similar question: [Footer with Javascript Array as source of data](http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/7326/footer-with-javascript-array-as-source-of-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add data to the footer, you need at least a footer

In your code `$(column.footer())` return nothing so the `select` are created but never added to the dom

```
<table id="example" class="display" width="100%">
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

If you don't want to add manually the footer structure, you can use the first part of the JS code below to create this footer

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var columns = [
        {title: "Name"}, 
        {title: "Position"}, 
        {title: "Office"}, 
        {title: "Extn."}, 
        {title: "Start date"}, 
        {title: "Salary"}
    ];

    // Footer construction
    var $tfoot = $("#example tfoot tr");
    for (var i = 0, len = columns.length; i < len ; i++){
        $tfoot.append("<th>");
    }
    
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        data: dataSet,
        columns: columns,
        initComplete: function (setting, json) {
            this.api().columns().every( function () {
                var column = this;
                var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                    .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                    .on( 'change', function () {
                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                            $(this).val()
                        );
 
                        column
                            .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                            .draw();
                    } );
 
                column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                    select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                } );
            } );
        } 
        
    } );
} );

var dataSet = [
  ["Airi Satou", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "5407", "2008/11/28", "$162,700"],
  ["Angelica Ramos", "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)", "London", "5797", "2009/10/09", "$1,200,000"],
  ["Gavin Joyce", "Developer", "Edinburgh", "8822", "2010/12/22", "$92,575"],
  ["Jennifer Chang", "Regional Director", "Singapore", "9239", "2010/11/14", "$357,650"],
  ["Brenden Wagner", "Software Engineer", "San Francisco", "1314", "2011/06/07", "$206,850"],
  ["Fiona Green", "Chief Operating Officer (COO)", "San Francisco", "2947", "2010/03/11", "$850,000"],
  ["Shou Itou", "Regional Marketing", "Tokyo", "8899", "2011/08/14", "$163,000"],
  ["Martena Mccray", "Post-Sales support", "Edinburgh", "8240", "2011/03/09", "$324,050"],
  ["Unity Butler", "Marketing Designer", "San Francisco", "5384", "2009/12/09", "$85,675"]
];
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/dt/jq-2.1.4,dt-1.10.9,b-1.0.3,b-flash-1.0.3/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/dt/jq-2.1.4,dt-1.10.9,b-1.0.3,b-flash-1.0.3/datatables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display" width="100%">
    <tfoot><tr></tr></tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Tried your solution but have no effect still.

Comment: @neversaint edited post with the same snippet that you have in your question. What do you mean by, no effect still ?